# Remove links from pictures to products inside cart

Tags: ubercart

I am using Drupal 6, and latest version of the Ubercart module. I am using this code to remove links from products names and images. However, links from images are not stripped. What should be wrong wit this code?

```
function <MODULENAME>_tapir_table_alter(&$table, $table_id) {
  switch ($table_id) {
    case 'uc_cart_view_table':
      foreach (element_children($table) as $i) {
        $table[$i]['image']['#value'] = strip_tags($table[$i]['image']['#value'], '<img>');
        $table[$i]['desc']['#value'] = strip_tags($table[$i]['desc']['#value'], '<div><ul><li>');
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, can't you use debugger?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with debugger, where can I find it? Thank you

Comment: Just google for php xdebug and IDE if you are using any

Comment: It seems to be quite complicated, I am not a developer/programmer. Can you help with this code I provided?

Comment: Unfortunately not because I am very busy right now.